# $_SESSION[] array elements in pHp

Tags: php, html, session, session-variables

How to use `$_SESSION[]` array elements among multiple pages of same website? And when/how to destroy them?
Error:

> Variable undefined..

If you have a better suggestion, please help me out.

Code for `action.php`

```
<?php
include 'someheader.php';
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['submit'])
{
    $_SESSION['name']=$_POST['name'];

    //Some Codes Here

}
include 'footer.php';
?>
```

Other php file in same  directory

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['name']))
{
     echo "Hi $_SESSION['name'].\n";
     echo "You have been logged in.";
 }
?>
```

Comment: You forgot a session_start(); at the beginning of your second php file.

Comment: Thanks to all of you for the response :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In php, it's better to put `session_start()` in the **first statement** line of php pages. Use it once per page, at the very top, before you plan to use any $_SESSION variables.

```
<?php
session_start();
```

To obtenir a value in session :

```
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$password = $_SESSION['password'];
```

To delete a value in session:

```
unset($_SESSION['temp']);
```

To destroy a session :

```
session_destroy();
```

Hope this could be helpful.

Comment: also worth noting you can set sessions to automatically start via [session.auto_start](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.auto-start)

Answer (score 1):

Each php file must have a `session_start()` to be able to access session variables. As for how to destroy them, check the [session_destroy](http://php.net/manual/es/function.session-destroy.php) function. When to destroy them? Well basically you do it when you no longer need them, for example when you log out.

Answer (score 0):

You should have this as the **first** line of every file that uses `$_SESSION`

```
session_start();
```

This makes it available in the current script. Here's the [basics](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp), see the note after the example. Otherwise, your usage is correct.